# Async issues when creating translator app with fragments & Microsoft API

Tags: android-asynctask, fragment, microsoft-translator

I'm creating a translator app for android using fragments (because I have tabs).

I found some good tutorials for translation with Microsoft's API, but none of them worked, until I found [this](https://github.com/boatmeme/microsoft-translator-android-test).

As an activity it works, when I change it to a fragment, it doesn't.

Here's the code after a small change:

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment 
    {
    TextView text;
    String translatedText;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        text=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.translatedtext);
        text.setText("<This text should change after translation has occurred in AsyncTask>");
         new MyAsyncTask() { 
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                text.setText(translatedText);
            }
        }.execute();
        return rootView;
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> 
    {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Translate.setClientId("MicrosoftTranslatorJavaAPI");
            Translate.setClientSecret("0VHbhXQnJrZ7OwVqcoX/PDZlyLJS9co3cVev1TPr8iM=");
            try {
                translatedText = Translate.execute("I should probably set this to something a little less profane", Language.ENGLISH, Language.FRENCH);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                translatedText = e.toString();
            }
            return true;
        }           
    }
}
```

The XML currently is just a simple TextView (like the Github example).

What do I have to change to make asynctask work?

Comment: Why do you have two "onPostExecute"s defined (the one in MyAsyncTask is overridden)? How do you create the fragment and place it in the activity?

Comment: I changed the "onPostExecute" to it's original look. Regarding the second question, i'm not sure what you mean. It's created when you call onCreateView no? And inflate is meant to show the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the solution weeks ago, but just now thought of sharing this.
The solution was somewhat simple and right under my nose.
The API **microsoft-translator-java-api-0.6.1-jar-with-dependencies** in my project, I added manually and it was just "floating" inside my project folder.
When I inserted it into the libs folder manually, it then appeared inside **Android Private Libraries**. Now the translation worked!